# Jquery functions doesn't work in IE8

Tags: jquery, function, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with my jquery. Currently i am programming a Website for a company. Everyone in this company uses the Internet Explorer 8. I use the jquery version 1.11, which normaly should work with the IE8. In Chrome and Firefox everything works fine.

Here is the JS File with functions:

```
window.onload = changeTypeColor();
window.onload = $(".container-fluid").slideUp();

function minimize(){
    $("#extendedSearchDiv").slideToggle();
}

function search(searchKey) {
    if(searchKey !==''){
        $("searchTitel").fadeOut();
        $('searchTitel[class*='+searchKey+']').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        alert(' ! Suchfeld darf nicht leer sein');
        $("#searchKey").css("border","2px solid red");
    }
}

//Filter Funktion
function filterType(i){
    $("feld").fadeOut();
    alert("Es wird nach " + i + " gefiltert");  
    $("feld").filter("."+i).fadeIn();
    //$("feld").filter("."+i).css("background-color","red");
    //css( "border-style", "solid" );
}   

function showAll(){ 
    $("feld").fadeOut();    
    $("searchTitel").fadeOut();
    $("feld").fadeIn();
    $("searchTitel").fadeIn();
    //$("feld").filter("."+i).css("background-color","red");
    //css( "border-style", "solid" );
}
```

We call for example the filter function with

```
<input type='Button' class='btn btn-default' name ='filterButton' value='Filter' onClick='filterType(categorySelect.value)/>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `$("feld").fadeOut();` what is `feld`? Use correct ID or Class selectors.

Comment: You're using `window.onload` completely wrong, use `$(document).ready` instead

Comment: I'm curious about your HTML, can you put that in the question. Looks like you made up a bunch of HTML elements, or forgot the `#` or `.` in the jQuery selectors.

Comment: You're not selecting anything with your code, unless you have tags that I've never heard of.  Your use of jQuery appears to be wrong.  Use `$(".classname")` or `$("#id")` - note the . or # before the selector, that you don't have!

Comment: The code shown has many potential problems, but without an example of your page's HTML it is only guesswork. Please post the HTML too :)

Comment: But the problem with the Jquerry only exists in the IE.
Because of that i think the php code should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Improper use of selector appeared here.
e.g. `$("feld")`.

If `feld` is `id` of that control than use `$("#feld")` and if its CSS class name then use `$(".feld")`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

But the ("feld") is tag not an id or a class